# Why isn't Windows 2003's backup scheduling working?

Tags: backup

I have a server loaded with windows 2003. It is scheduled for a system state backup using NTBackup utility. It worked fine as scheduled for sometime, but since a couple of days ago the scheduled backup isn't running, and now I have a  manual job of doing a backup daily.

Comment: Did you check the schedule task logs to see what error its reporting?

Comment: And if/when you do find the error in the event log - you can do some research on what might be causing it here:  http://eventid.net/

Comment: +1 @keltari - was going to write as my answer - the event log is very good and should tell you why it failed. My guess is connection or space on/to the backup drive/tape/whatever.

Comment: @william.. i guess you are ryt... actually the backup drive is an external network drive... may be due to connection prolems..